# Array Lists and Text File reading in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, text-files

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String courseName;
    private double exam1;
    private double exam2;
    private double exam3;

    public Student(String name, String courseName, double exam1, double exam2, double exam3) {
        this.name = name;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.exam1 = exam1;
        this.exam2 = exam2;
        this.exam3 = exam3;
    }
        public String toString() {
        calcGrade();
        String str = "Student: " + name + "\n\tClass Name: " + courseName + "\n\tGrade: " + grade;
        return str;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner (new File("students.txt"));
        ArrayList <Student> list = new ArrayList<>();


        while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
            list.add(new Student(fileIn.next(), fileIn.next(), fileIn.nextDouble(), fileIn.nextDouble(), fileIn.nextDouble()));
        }
        fileIn.close();
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }

}
```

What am I missing here? Program doesn't compile and I'm left with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
at ayers_hwk3.Ayers_Hwk3.main(Ayers_Hwk3.java:29)
```

I'm still very new to programming in Java and this one is way beyond me.

Comment: The problem is happening at runtime when the scanner tries to parse your input. Either there are not enough fields, or since the scanner breaks by default on white space, you might have more than two whitespace-delimited words before the numeric fields appear.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this as there might be a missing field, whitespace or newline in the file. 
So when you do fileIn.next*(), it throws a NoSuchElementException

Instead you can do something like this.

```
while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = fileIn.nextLine();
    String[] words = line.split(' ')
    list.add(new Student(words[0], words[1], words[2], words[3], words[4]);
 }
```

Incase this throws a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception, then print the words and find out the exact location of the mistake in the file.